# WebJob and ExceptionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, exception, attributes, azure-webjobs

I use ExceptionFilterAttribute for my web api application to catch different unhandled exceptions, i.e.:

```
public class InvalidDriverExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception != null)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext.Exception is Domain.InvalidDriverException)
            {
                var resp = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User is not a driver");
                actionExecutedContext.Response = resp;
            }
        }

        //base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

but I want to have similar engine for my web job. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created derived class from FunctionExceptionFilterAttribute

```
public class ErrorHandlerAttribute : FunctionExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(FunctionExceptionContext exceptionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string body = $"ErrorHandler called. Function '{exceptionContext.FunctionName}': {exceptionContext.FunctionInstanceId} failed. ";
        CombineErrorWithAllInnerExceptions(exceptionContext.Exception, ref body);

        string[] emailList = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendErrorEmails"].Split(';');

        await SendEmail.SendErrorNotificationAsync("WebJob - Common Driver Error", body);
    }

    private void CombineErrorWithAllInnerExceptions(Exception ex, ref string error)
    {
        error += $"ExceptionMessage: '{ex.Message}'.";
        if (ex is Domain.BadStatusCodeException)
        {
            error += $"Status code: {((Domain.BadStatusCodeException)ex).StatusCode}";
        }

        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            error += $"InnerEx: ";
            CombineErrorWithAllInnerExceptions(ex.InnerException, ref error);
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it for method:

```
    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    [ErrorHandler]
    public async Task GetDriversAsync(TextWriter logger)
    {
```

when exception occurs it call this code and send notification email to me

Answer (score 1):

> but I want to have similar engine for my web job. Is it possible?

Yes.  But because web jobs are continuous or schedule, there are some differences in how they are implemented.  You could use **ErrorTrigger** to achieve your goal. An error trigger that allows you to annotate functions to be automatically called by the runtime when errors occur.  It could monitor errors in web job when it is executed.My Demo result like this:[filter null exception](https://image.ibb.co/je01Lc/catchnullwebjob.gif). For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/monitoring-errors-in-azure-webjobs-with-the-errortrigger-extension).

> When developing jobs with Azure WebJob, it's a good practice to implement error monitoring in case something goes wrong when a job is executed.
>
> The WebJobs ErrorTrigger extension, part of the Core extensions, will help us achieve that.